# Parsing whitespace-oriented conf file with Regex

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm trying to parse a gitolite.conf file, which is a whitespace-oriented conf file with a few regexes. The worst problem is that some options might appear anywhere:

```
@staff              =   dilbert alice           # line 1
@projects           =   foo bar                 # line 2

repo @projects baz                              # line 3
    RW+             =   @staff                  # line 4
    -       master  =   ashok                   # line 5
    RW              =   ashok                   # line 6
    R               =   wally                   # line 7

    config hooks.emailprefix = '[%GL_REPO] '    # line 8
```

Check the "master" attribute. Some repos have them, others do not. It's a real pain.

Comment: Sure sounds like a hassle.

Comment: Regex is not the right tool.

Comment: Given the input text in your question, what is the expected output ?

Comment: Why not? How would you parse that?

Comment: Please consider to show us requested output format

Comment: There's no way anyone can answer your question without further explanation of your requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes a goal of extracting *key/value* pairs into capturing groups, where *key* consists of contiguous non-whitespace before `=` and *value* includes everything after `=` but before `#`, trimmed of leading/trailing whitespace.

**Basic version**

```
([^\s]+)\s*=\s*((?:\s*[^\s#]+)*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**More advanced version**

The regex above doesn't handle quoted strings very well (e.g. `prefix = '  Quoted with # and leading/trailing whitespace '`). Regex isn't great at this kind of thing but simple cases can be handled as follows:

```
([^\s]+)\s*=\s*('[^']*'|"[^"]*"|(?:(?:\s*[^\s#]+)*))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Here's the demo if you need to see what is captured and play around with it more: [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/YYNmkLaZ0O1CZanh)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should know that this isn't entirely possible with Regex. Regex is a great tool for parsing **regular** languages (including some types of configuration files), but as soon as you get into "Well, this line is actually a header line and we need all lines under it, and some lines might have this token, and others might not", it gets quite messy. I'm not saying it's impossible, but you're going to waste a *lot* of time debugging your Regex pattern instead of just writing a parser in whatever language you're using this with.

Second, if you're going to ask a quesiton about Regex, it is always helpful to know what you want out of the expression. Do you want to tokenize everything, do you only want the configuration keys, do you only want the comments?

That being said, I took my best guess, here's an expression to get you started:

```
^(?:([^=#]+?)\s.?=?\s.?([^=#]+?)\s.?(?:#|$))
```

With this expression, please apply the `g` and `m` flags (global and multiline). In PCRE, this would look like:

```
/^(?:([^=#]+?)\s.?=?\s.?([^=#]+?)\s.?(?:#|$))/gm
```

There are two capture groups, one is whatever is before the `=` sign, and the other is whatever is after. If there is no `=` sign, the first capture group contains everything. Anything after "#" is ignored.

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate: http://www.rexfiddle.net/eQexbZU

Comment: The g modifier doesn't exist in pcre.

Comment: The asker didn't specify what language they were using, and in most modern languages that implement some form of PCRE, the global modifier is valid (JavaScript, Perl, etc). If global is not available, there are other language-specific ways to implement a global-esque flag.